# How can I append two arrays, but have the second array in wide format? Python

Tags: python, append

If I have two arrays in python:

```
Array 1 =

[[1 2]
 [3 4]]

Array 2 = 
[[5 6]]
```

How can I use .append or .extend to create an array, such that:

```
Array 3:
[[1 2 5 6]
 [3 4 5 6]]
```

Comment: It's not clear what data you are starting with. Since this is a python question, please make the code samples valid python, then there will be no confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have numpy arrays, you can broadcast the second array to the shape of the first, and concatenate along the second axis with:

```
array1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
array2 = np.array([5,6])

np.c_[array1, np.broadcast_to(array2, array1.shape)]

array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the second array to the first one using `np.append` with `axis=1`.

```
array1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
array2 = np.array([[5,6]])
```

Make sure the shape match while appending, use `broadcast_to` to help with this

```
array3 = np.append(array1, np.broadcast_to(array2,array1.shape), axis=1)

[[1 2 5 6]
 [3 4 5 6]]
```